# not able to append html using jQuery (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, append

In this jquery plugin:

http://www.stahs.org.uk/jquery.infinitecarousel.bak

There's this line:

```
            $(obj).append('<div id="textholder'+randID+'" class="textholder" style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;margin-bottom:'+-imgHeight*o.textholderHeight+'px;left:'+$(obj).css('paddingLeft')+'"></div>');
```

Problem is when it dumps the text node in this div, it aligns to the top of the div. I want text to align to bottom of div. So I decided to create another div within this div:

```
$(obj).append('<div id="textholder'+randID+'" class="textholder" style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;margin-bottom:'+-imgHeight*o.textholderHeight+'px;left:'+$(obj).css('paddingLeft')+'"></div>');
            console.log($('#textholder'+randID));
            $('#textholder'+randID).append('<div style="display:table-cell; height: 94.25px; width: 1000px; vertical-align:bottom;"></div>');
```

The console outputs this:

```
[div#textholder35196647.textholder]
[div#textholder62315889.textholder]
[div#textholder95654959.textholder]
```

However, my above append is not working. The nested div never shows up, so when I later do this:

```
                    if(t != null)
                {
                    $('#textholder'+randID+' div').html(t).animate({marginBottom:'0px'},500); // Raise textholder
                    showminmax();
                }
```

No text becomes visible because the nested div never gets created.

So I am extremely confused. If you look at original plugin, this line works:

```
 $('#textholder'+randID+' div').html(t)
```

How is it able to target the right div here yet when I append to it right after it's created, it doesn't exist, as you guys suggest?

This doesn't work either:

```
                var $texthold = jQuery('<div id="textholder'+randID+'" class="textholder" style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;margin-bottom:'+-imgHeight*o.textholderHeight+'px;left:'+$(obj).css('paddingLeft')+'"></div>');
            $(obj).append($texthold);
            $texthold.append('<div></div>')
```

Thanks for response.

Comment: *"height: 94.25px"* Really? 94 and a quarter *pixels*? ;-)

Comment: Are you certain that <div id='textholderRAND_ID'> actually exists before you try to append to it? Have you verified in Firebug? Can you create a repro using jsFiddle.net? This is standard DOM manipulation code, which jQuery excels at. So I'm surprised that it's not working.

Comment: @crowder, did you know that diff 3 divs with 33.33px measurements can add up to 99px or 100px, depending on the browser? I ran into this problem a while back, and ended up storing the decimal remainder and adding it to the last one to keep consistent heights.

Comment: @Matrym: Or, you know, use 33.33, 33.33, and 33.34. :-) It's just that fractions of a pixel don't make any sense at the HTML level. (They can do at the display driver level, if dealing with a flat panel display with subpixel rendering.)

Comment: @Crowder Understood and agreed about decimals being nonsense per pixel, but I'm just sharing an interesting discovery. Some browsers won't round up 33.9999px. If you want to fit 12 months as divs into a 100px height container, this can cause problems, so you need to store the decimal and carry it over to the next container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this worked:

```
            function showtext(t)
            {

                if(t != null)
                {   

                    if(typeof $('#textholder'+randID).find('div')[0] == 'undefined'){
                        $('#textholder'+randID).append('<div style="display:table-cell; height: 94.25px; vertical-align:bottom;"></div>');
                    }

                    $('#textholder'+randID+' div').html(t);

                    $('#textholder'+randID).animate({marginBottom:'0px'},500); // Raise textholder
                    showminmax();

                }
            }
```

It's just kind of crazy I had to resort to using typeof to check whether div is declared or not. Why the author of the plugin decided to randomly assign integers as ids of divs is beyond me. By doing that, it appears javascript has difficulty retaining the randomly created id. That's my only explanation for the unusual behavior I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though perhaps `randID` has been modified between the `$(obj).append`... line and your added `$('#textholder'+randID)`... line. Are you quite sure the value of `randID` is the same on the two lines?

Comment: I was just going to say that it looks like randID isn't even defined if he is adding the second div in his own code, instead of in the plugin

Comment: I updated question with the console output. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that $(obj) really refers to the element you want to append to? Just in case, you might want to try it the other way round:

```
$('<div id="textholder'+randID+'" class="textholder" style="position:absolute;' 
    +'bottom:0px;margin-bottom:'+(-imgHeight*o.textholderHeight)
    +'px;left:'+$(obj).css('paddingLeft')+'"></div>'
).appendTo(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(obj).after('html');
```

Documentation is [here](http://api.jquery.com/after/).